# Angular eventListener from Component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I want to be able to update an image SRC attribute from an uploaded image in an `<input type="file" id="fileLoader">`, i have already this using vanilla JS. How do i do do the same in Angular component

my codes are below

Using JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('#fileLoader').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var img = document.querySelector('img');
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});


<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
```

how do i replicate this in angular component?

Comment: "how do i replicate this in angular component?" Unclear what your problem is. How do you add event listeners to an element in a component?

Comment: if you where to do the same thing my code does in angular component ?

Comment: You also do not state the version of Angular.

Comment: Angular cli: 8.3.19

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this quite a lot in my opinion

1) use two way data binding and ngModel to bind your url value to your input:

```
<!-- your input element -->
<input type="file" (change)="uploadImage($event)"/>
```

3) in your component

```
// extract the url of the data and let it appear
public uploadImage(event: any) {
  this.myModel = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
}
```

2) your image

```
<img [src]="myModel">
```

this should work!

Comment: not sure how that would work with a file input.... it is not a textbox the user has.

Comment: if that's a file input just use the (change) event listener to a function that sets the url...

Comment: like this you mean `<input type="file" id="fileLoader" (change)="upload(this)"/>` and `upload(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      const avatarImg: HTMLImageElement = document.querySelector('img');
      avatarImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }`

Comment: No, you can use the event to directly access your file

Comment: Still nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Mikegross answer is correct but not complete. Angular's sanitizer mechanism will whine about that url. You need to by pass it.
Like this :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  myModel: string | any = "";
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  public uploadImage(event: any) {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    this.myModel = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sq1t2n) sample